# How to re-execute an activity of tab activity

Tags: android, android-tabactivity

I’m developing an android app in which I have using two tabs by make use of TabActivity. It also has action bar. There is a search bar in action bar that is used to filter data coming from server.

So the problem here is when I use search bar the tab data must get filtered but I’m unable to do so.

How to re-execute an activity of tab activity. Any suggestions or code samples are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `TabActivity` has been deprecated for **three and a half years** at this point. Please use something else for your tabs, such as a `ViewPager` with a tabbed indicator, `FragmentTabHost`, or even a classic `TabHost` using views for the tabs. Then, handling your search is just a matter of calling the appropriate method on the fragment or activity that serves as the controller for whatever needs to be filtered.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. we will follow that. But isn't there any way to do that using TabActivity.